# Perform a series of tasks with an interval in between each

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-java2

I am looking to make a series of function calls with intervals between each call. Can assume each function call to be a print statement printing a unique String. Assume we want to wait for 500 ms between each function call. How can I go about with this in RxJava?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this by using a `Completable` that executes an `Action`.

A sample is below:

```
    println("33")
    Completable.fromAction { println("75") }
            .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .andThen(Completable.fromAction { println("82") })
            .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .andThen(Completable.fromAction { println("93") })
            .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .andThen(Completable.fromAction { println("101") })
            .subscribe()
```

The above code prints `33` and `75` immediately, and then waits 5 seconds, prints `82`, waits 5 seconds, ...and so on.